# PHP dynamic form variables

Tags: php, arrays, forms, variables, dynamic

I posted this over at the wordpress development site but am getting no bites.  It is still a php issue, so I'm hoping someone here can help me out.

I am trying to create a dynamic form in the wordpress admin where I can add a line and still be able to process the variables into the database as post meta. I've done quite a bit of research and have tried several methods but cant seem to get it work. I have a sample of my code here to show how I am processing the info, I just need to figure out how to loop through the dynamic content and then properly update or delete it as necessary.

```
<?php 

// Set Up Meta Boxes

function add_invoice_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box('invoice_meta_box', 'Invoice Summary', 'setup_invoice_meta_box', 'invoice', 'normal', 'high');
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_invoice_meta_boxes');

// Invoice Meta Box
function setup_invoice_meta_box($post) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="invoice_meta_box_nonce" value="'. wp_create_nonce('invoice_meta_box'). '" />';

?>

<script language="javascript">function addRow(tableID){var table=document.getElementById(tableID);var rowCount=table.rows.length;var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);var colCount=table.rows[0].cells.length;for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++){var newcell=row.insertCell(i);newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type){case"text":newcell.childNodes[0].value="";break;case"checkbox":newcell.childNodes[0].checked=false;break;case"select-one":newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex=0;break;}}}
function deleteRow(tableID){try{var table=document.getElementById(tableID);var rowCount=table.rows.length;for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){var row=table.rows[i];var chkbox=row.cells[0].childNodes[0];if(null!=chkbox&&true==chkbox.checked){if(rowCount<=1){alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");break;}
table.deleteRow(i);rowCount--;i--;}}}catch(e){alert(e);}}</script>

<?php } ?>

<div class="wrap">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')">
<input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th width="20px">&nbsp;</th>
    <th width="202px">Product</th>
    <th width="252px">Description</th>
    <th width="52px">QTY</th>
    <th width="102px">Price</th>
    <th width="102px">Tax</th>
    <th width="202px">Amount</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <table id="dataTable">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="gho-chk" name="chk"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="gho-description" name="product[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'product[]', true); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="gho-description" name="description[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'description[]', true); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="gho-qty" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'qty[]', true); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="gho-price" name="price[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'price[]', true); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="gho-tax" name="tax[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'tax[]', true); ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="gho-amount" name="amount[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post_>ID, 'amount[]', true); ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<?php 
function save_invoice_meta_box($post_id) {
    // check nonce
    if (!isset($_POST['invoice_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['invoice_meta_box_nonce'], 'invoice_meta_box')) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check capabilities
    if ('invoice' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // exit on autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['product'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'product', $_POST['product']);
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'product');
    }

}

add_action('save_post', 'save_invoice_meta_box');

?>
```

Comment: Why do you have separate sub-tables for the column headings and the input fields?

Comment: And you seem to have an extra `</tr>` on the line after the first `<table>`.

Comment: `$post_>ID` is a typo for `$post->ID`.

Comment: Where do you set `$post` that's used in the calls to `get_post_meta()`? It seems like the code that creates the table rows should be in a loop that processes all the posts.

Comment: I have separate sub-tables so the javascript can add a line to the table for additional entries without adding a new table header also.  I'm sure there is a better approach but it worked for me.

Comment: Yes I see the typo on $post->ID, but that is just on here not in the actual code I am using.  The line:  `if(isset($_POST['product'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'product', $_POST['product']);
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'product');
    }` is an example of where the $post info gets added.  This is just an example.  I am wanting to know how to loop through dynamically created $post

Comment: If you want to loop through it, it needs to be an array, so you can do `$post[$i]->ID`.

Comment: Please fix all the typos in the question.

Comment: You can separate the table into separate header and body using `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags.

Comment: How do I save the post meta?  Where `update_post_meta` for example do I simply put `product[]` or will I need a different way to update it?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're doing. Shouldn't the table be built from the database, not the post data?

Comment: No I am inserting data from a dynamic form into the database and once it is saved, displaying that information on the form in editable format.  This is in a custom post type in wordpress backend.

Comment: All the `$_POST` variables from the table will be arrays. You need to loop over them to process all the inputs.

Comment: sorry im not getting this to work.  I was hoping for an example, if I knew how to loop through this I would do it.  This is a PHP area I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

When you give inputs names ending in `[]`, PHP turns those `$_POST` or `$_GET` parameters into arrays.  Then you loop through the content like this:

```
if (isset_($_POST['product'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['product'] as $i => $product) {
        // Do something with $product, $_POST['description'][$i], $_POST['qty'][$i], etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made a simplified version using your code, I had to add an (array) otherwise it threw a php error: `if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    foreach ((array) $_POST['test'] as $i => $test) {
    // Do something with $product, $_POST['description'][$i], $_POST['qty'][$i], etc.
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'test', $_POST['test'][$i]);
    } 
   }` When I dynamically add a second line to the form, it only saves the 2nd entry to the db

Comment: I don't know why you need to do that. If the input says `name="test[]"` then it should be an array automatically.